# Symfony - Live Server

Tags: php, git, symfony, process

I already have some years experience with php, but now
i would like to create a new symfony2-project,

1. development-website
2. production-website

Anyone could explain me how to process this?

Should i work with git?

Greetings!

Comment: use git and its bare post update hook to pull into your production env, use parameters.prod.yml and parameters.dev.yml and symlink on each stage as parameters.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can work with git
- In symfony2 the dev environment is only called by url http://example.com/app_dev.php/
  Also in app/config/ have config_dev.yml config_prod.yml

Do you want a separate code and database in dev and prod? In that case git with branches sounds great.

Comment: thanks! is there any tutorial how to setup branches using git with symfony2 ? i couldnt find anything..

Comment: Hi for symfony2 in git only consider gitignore file. The workflow with branches are the same that it is no symfony2. Hope the following links help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html http://symfony.es/documentacion/como-configurar-bien-el-archivo-gitignore-para-las-aplicaciones-symfony2/ http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-branches-without-a-conflict/ http://gitref.org/branching/